# Delete a TableViev Row on selecting a checkbox in that row and in the last column

Tags: java, javafx

I am attempting to make it so that whenever I select a checkbox in the last column of my tableviwew, I delete said row. I have a Task object I input into the tableview with relevant fields String name, String dateString and boolean tickOff. Can someone help?

This is that class:

```
public class Task {

private BooleanProperty tickOff;
private String name;
private String description;
private String dateString;
private String reminder1, reminder2, reminder3, reminder4, reminder5, reminder6;
private int year, month, day;

public Task(String name, String description, int year, int month, int day, boolean ticoff) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    dateString = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    this.tickOff = new SimpleBooleanProperty(ticoff);
    // this.tickOff = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    /*
     * this.tickOff.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() { public void
     * changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
     * 
     * System.out.println("Hi");
     * 
     * } });
     */
}

/////////////
public boolean getSelected() {
    return selectedProperty().get();
}

public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
    return this.tickOff;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return this.tickOff.get();
}

public boolean getickOff() {
    return this.tickOff.get();
}

public BooleanProperty getTickOff() {
    return this.tickOff;
}

public BooleanProperty checkedProperty() {
    return this.tickOff;
}
```

This is the Controller class of my scene where the tableviwew resides.

```
public class ClassPlanController {


private TableView<Task> tasks;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, String> task;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, String> date;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, Boolean> done;




public void addTaskToList(Task taskName) {
    
    task.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateString"));
    done.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tickOff"));


/*
    done.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer param) {
            return tasks.getItems().get(param).checkedProperty();
            
        }

    }));
    
    /*
      done.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Task, Boolean>, TableCell<Task, Boolean>>() {

        public TableCell<Task, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Task, Boolean> p) {
            return new CheckBoxTableCell<Task, Boolean>();
        }

    });
     
    done.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer param) {

            return tasks.get(param).checkedProperty();

        }

    }));
    
    */
        

    tasks.getItems().add(taskName);
    tasks.setEditable(true);
    
}
```

Comment: If you really want to keep all the tasks (even those which are not displayed in the table), use a `FilteredList` and filter by the Boolean property. If you want to get rid of the checked tasks entirely, probably a button makes more sense than a check box.

Comment: this is not a code writing service .. do some research, apply what you learned and come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's wrong

Comment: @James_D i am trying to make it emulate a to-do list, so it's pretty essential

Comment: @kleopatra i never asked for any code to be written. i did research and a solution is nowhere to be found, presumably why I'm here asking the question. I think this fits the minimal reproducible example for the context, if theres any missing, feel free to tell me and I will update the question.

Comment: You misunderstood me. Do you want to discard the item entirely (i.e. have no further reference to it), or do you still want to keep it in memory (so, e.g., you can display completed tasks, etc) and just not show it in the table? (Either way, I suppose, it's a pretty weird user experience for something to disappear from the UI entirely when you check a check box.)

Comment: It's hard to imagine what a solution to the question you posted looks like without you expecting people to write code for you. What do you actually want here?

Comment: @James_D oh, sorry then. Just remove from the table is fine, thanks. Right now I am storing the java objects in txt file lines and I will populate the tableview via that doc. I know how to do that (at least I do with list views so I presume implementing that for a tableview will be easy enough), however despite researching this for ages I can't find a way to remove a row from the tableview on click of the checkbox. Here's an image of my tableview: https://imgur.com/a/GgMHifB

Comment: What's wrong with my earlier suggestion: use a `FilteredList`.

Comment: I mean it seems like a bit of a hassle given that I already have this and I got it up to this point. I just need to make it so that when I press the check box in the last column, the row in which that column was gets deleted. Like I  guess a more general way of asking this would be how to assign an action event to a checkbox in a tableview

Comment: What are you talking about? How is it a "hassle" to use a `FilteredList`? It will do exactly what you are asking for,.

Comment: Bro look I'm sorry for wasting your time but I looked it up quickly and it doesn't seem to be what I need, I've never heard of a filtered list and it doesn't show up when i search for it in scenebuilder. How does the filtered list change anything?

Comment: *"How does the filtered list change anything?"* It filters what is shown in the table., which is what you said you wanted. It's a filtered list. Read the documentation.

Comment: _this fits the minimal reproducible example for the context_ actually .. no: I don't see anything in your sinppets that at least tries to remove the row nor even to listen to changes of boolean

Comment: Well because I don't know how to do any of that. I guess I should have asked how to listen to boolean changes? I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `FilteredList`:

```
public class ClassPlanController {


    private TableView<Task> tasks;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> task;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> date;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, Boolean> done;
    
    private final ObservableList<Task> taskList = FXCollections.observableArrayList<>(task -> new Observable[] {task.checkedProperty()});
    
    
    public void initialize() {
        task.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateString"));
        done.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().checkedProperty());
    
        done.setCellFactory(column -> new CheckBoxTableCell(index -> tasks.getItems().get(index).checkedProperty()));
    
        tasks.setItems(new FilteredList(taskList, task -> ! task.checkedProperty().get()));
    
    }
    
    public void addTaskToList(Task taskName) {
        
        taskList.add(taskName);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, you're a legend man. Thanks for taking the time to help me. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Yo, sorry for bothering again, just a quick q. Is there a way to add a Thread.sleep() line anywhere to delay the deleting, I want the checkbox to appear and then for it to be deleted. Thanks

Comment: Never sleep on the fx application thread. I said in the comments that this would be an awful user experience for exactly this reason.

Comment: @Tomislav Probably the way to do this would be to implement the table cell yourself with listeners on the check box which start a transition and update the model property when the transition finishes. That’s a pretty complex undertaking.

Comment: I can't tell if the last part's sarcastic or not haha. But yeah I basically don't understand what any of that means.

Comment: Hey so, while I managed to implement your solution successfully, I don't see how I can utilize this to use the checkbox as an action event. Like I get how the code works that you sent me just reading over it, but I don't see how I can make for instance ticking a check box on the tableviwew return the row number it was in (just as an example). Is there a way to easily implement this on top of what you already gave me? Thanks

Comment: You need to implement the cell yourself. The cell contains the checkbox, and the event handler for the check box. I. The event handler, you can call the cell’s `getIndex()` method (defined in the superclass), which gives you the index of the row the cell is currently displayed in.

Comment: Does that mean make a CheckBoxTableCell class in my project or? Again I am sorry for seemingly stupid questions but this really is a challenge for me.

Comment: @Tomislav If you want to do what you describe, you need to implement your own `TableCell` subclass, instead of using the pre-made `CheckBoxTableCell`

Comment: I created my own checkboxtablecell class, are there any suggestions you have for me to check and see what I must modify?

Comment: Nvm, figured it out solo. I don't know I did it but I managed to do it with my limited intuition. I thank you for all of your help, I will post the extended answer in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241531/discussion-between-tomislav-and-james-d).

Comment: _you need to implement your own TableCell subclass, instead of using the pre-made CheckBoxTableCell_ actually, I tend to disagree here - the cell _must not_ implement any data logic. Instead, I would use a custom boolean property that does it that's loosely bound to the model.

Comment: btw: _I don't see how I can utilize this to use the checkbox as an action event_ why would you? Don't think _view_, do think _model_: on the latter you have the ticked property which you can listen to. As to delete vs. filter: the former seems like bad UX (what if the user later detects that s/he forgot anything?) By filtering, all tasks are still there and you can add options to show all/done/not-yet-done task by simply setting the predicate as needed.

Comment: @kleopatra The original question, solved by using a filtered list, was to only display items for which the property bound to the check box is false. That’s a hideous user experience, because you check a box and it immediately disappears. The OP asked for a delay. So I was envisioning implementing the cell so that there was a delay between checking the box and updating the model. You could perhaps have a fade transition which starts when the box is checked and the model is updated (and the item hidden) when the fade completes, for example. Those are all view responsibilities.

Comment: Of course, there’s a lot to do for that. What if, eg, the cell is reused during the transition. And there are probably a lot of other considerations I haven’t thought about.

Comment: _The OP asked for a delay... fade transition .. all view responsibilities_ all true, my bad I didn't see it :) But then, as you already noted, beyond entry level fx knowledge and all well beyond the scope of the question (which is already too broad, to start with). FilteredList is the way to go for now. If the assignment asked for using action on the checkbox, it's either asking for the wrong or we don't know the complete context of the current lesson (very high probability)

Answer (score -2):

To allow ActionEvents to be assigned to a CheckBoxTableCell, create your own Class called `CheckBoxTableCell` as follows:

```
    private ObservableValue<T> ov;
    private TableView<Task> tableView; //The table that will house the checkbox.

    public CheckBoxTableCell() {

        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        this.checkBox = checkBox;

        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    // getTableView().getSelectionModel().select( getIndex() );
                    System.out.println("Xd");
                } else {
                    // getTableView().getSelectionModel().clearSelection( getIndex() );
                    System.out.println("Nothing");
                }
            }
        });

        setGraphic(checkBox);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        // System.out.println("updateItem");
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);

        } else {

            setGraphic(checkBox);

            if (ov instanceof BooleanProperty) {

                checkBox.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional((BooleanProperty) ov);

            }

            ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
            if (ov instanceof BooleanProperty) {

                checkBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional((BooleanProperty) ov);

            }

        }

    }

    void setTableView(TableView<Task> tableView) {
        this.tableView = tableView;
    }

    void setTableColumn(TableColumn<Task, Boolean> tableColumn) {
        this.tableColumn = tableColumn;
    }
}
```

Comment: why re-invent the wheel? what's wrong with CheckBoxTableCell?

Comment: a couple of comments to your re-invention: a) an empty cell is unselected and has no graphic (good!), but your constructor instantiates it with graphic b) the constructor with parameter is unused, remove it c) the cell is the wrong place implement data related logic - like removing rows - (as you seem to intent doing in the selection listener), implement it on the data d) the selection listener looks fishy: it competes with the bidi-binding, there is no guarantee about their notification sequence, so might (and probably) poses problems on cell re-use

Comment: You lost me with all those technical terms. All I know after implementing it this way checking a checkbox actually did something (In this case print 1 when ticked and 0 when unticked.) Is there a way to add to add code that removes the table row it is in? The solution James_D told me worked fine to remove from the table on clicking the checkbox but this way I feel like it's more customizable. Like I don't just need the rows to be removed, I also need the row indexes so I may remove lines from a text file where I store objects as JSON strings.

Comment: The reason why I re-did it is because the regular class you import (javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell) doesn't seemingly do anything when ticked off, and James_D suggested I make my own one to edit events when checked off. He mentioned using getIndex() to get the location of the cell but I can't seem to understand how I am to implement that. Should I create a new question?

Comment: _doesn't seemingly do anything when ticked off_ that's because it should not - implement your application logic in your model (vs. in the view) btw: to me it looks like you are building the penthouse before the cellar - no offense meant, but that's what your comments seem to indicate :) In other words: in your shoes I would try to get a thorough understanding of fx basics (in particular about how cells are working in this scenario) first

Comment: A very big deadline is encroaching for school, so learning all of t his is sort of out of the question. I know everything I need to finish this app apart from 2 small issues I have, this and another unrelated one I will try to resolve later. I am not particularly offended, however I am in dire need of some help with this and I have little time at my disposal.

Comment: start earlier next time ;) Note that this site is __not__ a personal helpdesk but a community effort to build a knowledge base helpful for future readers. You don't understand (according to your own comments :) most of details of the suggestions, and probably you are the only one with that particular mixture of not/knowing .. on the bright side: if you really want to learn, every sentence you don't understand is a starter for research :)

Comment: Is it really not creating a knowledge base? I couldn't find what I needed anywhere. I get people are not obligated to help me but I think saying "use this like that" in a 2 sentence comment is not much to ask for. Maybe I'm blind as to how inarticulate and difficult I am to work with but that's my interpretation. I am not particularly concerned with optimizing and polishing my app to the highest standards, whatever works works.  I am just confused because I think the class I created above requires only 1 or 2 lines of code to return the cell row index that has been ticked.

Comment: _Is it really not creating a knowledge base_ is not useful because it's asking too much at once for a learning level that's too low: obviously you don't understand a 2 sentence _use this like that_ (as I deduct from _You lost me with all those technical terms_). Also: _whatever works works_ - that's fine for a quick hack, but not overly useful in a knowledge base .. btw: another thingy this site is not is a forum .. I'm off now.